# Finding covariance for choosing two of n prime numbers

Tags: probability

> Assume we choose two different numbers of the first n primes (Where X is the first number and Y is the second number was chosen), find the common probability distribution, covariance and $\rho (X,Y)$.

I think the  common probability is $P(X=n_1,Y=n_2)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $n_1$=$n_2$} \\
\frac{1}{n^2}, & \text{else (Probability of $\frac {1}{n-1}$)}
\end{cases}$. I also calculated the variance and expectex value for X and for Y. When I tried to calculate the covariance I had to calculate which values can XY get. It seems that it gets every value in shape of $n_i\cdot n_j (j\neq i)$ but I can't find their probabilities (Number of times a value is gotten grows with i). How can I find these probabilies (in order to calculate $\mathbb E[XY]$)?

Comment: The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have not been defined. My guess is that one prime is chosen, then another, and somehow $X$ is connected with the first choice, and $Y$ with the second. Perhaps $X$ is the first prime chosen. Or perhaps it is the "number" of the first prime chosen. I am reasonably sure that $X$ and $Y$ are carefully defined in the actual problem.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. fixed.

Comment: Presumably all permitted choices are equally likely, though that has not been specified. There are $n(n-1)$ values of the ordered pair $(X,Y)$.

Comment: $P\{X=p_i, Y= p_j\}= 1/[n(n-1)]$  for  $i \neq j$,  where $p_i$  is the ith prime.

Comment: isn't it half of that (we count $p_i,p_j$ and $p_j,p_i$  as one couple)?

Comment: @Coargu: That would not make sense, for then what would be $X$ and what would be $Y$?

Comment: Seems logical. by the way, if they weren't different the common distribution was $\frac 1 {n^2}$?

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn but how can I calculate the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[XY]=\frac1{n(n-1)}[\sum_i \sum_j p_i p_j - \sum_i p_i^2]$

$EX = EY = \frac1n \sum_i p_i$

I don't know of any other way to express it.  Perhaps there is some number theory function, and perhaps one can establish  an asymptotic formula.